# Average calculator with user input Java - " java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found "

Tags: java

I'm creating a simple average calculator using user input on Eclipse, and I am getting this error:
" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found "  at

```
String input = sc.nextLine();
```

Also I think there will be follow up errors because I am not sure if I can have two variables string and float for user input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers you would like to average. Enter \"done\"");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        float num = sc.nextFloat();
        float sum = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        float average = 0;
        while(input != "done"){
            sum += num;
            counter ++;
            average = sum / counter;
        }
        System.out.println("The average of the "+ counter + " numbers you entered is " + average);

    }

}
```

Thanks a lot:)

Comment: add condition to enter count of number and move sc.nextLine() into loop to accept all number, or can use nextFloat in loop

Comment: Maybe parse the input, be it a float or String, to a float. If it parses, then continue with averaging, else, see if it equals “done” by using sc.nextLine() and break the loop if it is “done”.

Comment: Also make sure to use the correct comparator for Strings which would be input.equals(“done”). You can put a ! before the word “input” to signify “not”

Comment: Could you elaborate on "add condition to enter count of number", please? sanjeevRm

Comment: first input to be how many numbers to be considered for average

Comment: float count = sc.nextFloat();
  for(float i=0; i<count; i++){
   
   float num = sc.nextFloat();
   sum += num;
  }
  average= sum/count;

Answer (score 3):

First, the precision of `float` is just so bad that you're doing yourself a disservice using it. You should always use `double` unless you have a very specific need to use `float`.

When comparing strings, use `equals()`. See "[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/5221149)" for more information.

Since it seems you want the user to keep entering numbers, you need to call [`nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--) as part of the loop. And since you seem to want the user to enter text to end input, you need to call [`hasNextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble--) to prevent getting an `InputMismatchException`. Use `next()` to get a single word, so you can check if it is the word `"done"`.

Like this:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double sum = 0;
int counter = 0;
System.out.println("Enter the numbers you would like to average. Enter \"done\"");
for (;;) { // forever loop. You could also use 'while (true)' if you prefer
    if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        double num = sc.nextDouble();
        sum += num;
        counter++;
    } else {
        String word = sc.next();
        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("done"))
            break; // exit the forever loop
        sc.nextLine(); // discard rest of line
        System.out.println("\"" + word + "\" is not a valid number. Enter valid number or enter \"done\" (without the quotes)");
    }
}
double average = sum / counter;
System.out.println("The average of the "+ counter + " numbers you entered is " + average);
```

*Sample Output*

```
Enter the numbers you would like to average. Enter "done"
1
2 O done
"O" is not a valid number. Enter valid number or enter "done" (without the quotes)
0 done
The average of the 3 numbers you entered is 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few issues with this code:

1. Since you want to have the user either enter a number or the command "done", you have to use `sc.nextLine();`. This is because if you use both `sc.nextLine();` and `sc.nextFloat();`, the program will first try to receive a string and then a number.
2. You aren't updating the input variable in the loop, it will only ask for one input and stop.
3. And string comparing is weird in Java (you can't use `!=` or `==`). You need to use `stra.equals(strb)`.

To implement the changes:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers you would like to average. Enter \"done\"");
        
        float sum = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        String input = sc.nextLine();
        while (true) {
            try {
                //Try interpreting input as float
                sum += Float.parseFloat(input);
                counter++;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                //Turns out we were wrong!
                //Check if the user entered done, if not notify them of the error!
                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("done"))
                    break;
                else
                    System.out.println("'" + input + "'" + " is not a valid number!");
            }
            // read another line
            input = sc.nextLine();
        }
        
        // Avoid a divide by zero error!
        if (counter == 0) {
            System.out.println("You entered no numbers!");
            return;
        }

        // As @Andreas said in the comments, even though counter is an int, since sum is a float, Java will implicitly cast coutner to an float.
        float average = sum / counter;
        System.out.println("The average of the "+ counter + " numbers you entered is " + average);

    }

}
```

Comment: There is no need to cast `counter` to `float`. The language will implicitly do that for you. It's called [numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6-500).

Comment: Silently ignoring errors is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Andreas, although I usually would agree, and actually, I like your solution better (I didn't know about hasNextDouble). I would argue that since I am only catching a NumberFormatException in a code block that will specifically do string to float conversion, it's not the biggest sin.

Comment: Me dumb user. Me enters `1 S 6 O done`, and since 1 + 5 + 6 + 0 = 12 and 12 / 4 = 3, I expect the program to tell me the average is 3, but it says the average is 3.5 *(since `(1+6)/2 = 3.5`)*. Me not understand.  --- Now, if the program had not silently ignored the errors and had told me that `S` and `O` are not valid numbers and have been ignored, I would understand, but it didn't tell me that. --- Dumb program not working, me sad! 

Comment: @Andreas, lol who would've known I'd be learning UI principles when posting an answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers you would like to average. Enter \"done\" at end : ");        
        
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        float num = 0;
        float sum = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        float average = 0;
        while(!"done".equals(input)){           
            num = Float.parseFloat(input);  // parse inside loop if its float value
            sum += num;
            counter ++;
            average = sum / counter;
            input = scanner.nextLine();  // get next input at the end
        }
        System.out.println("The average of the "+ counter + " numbers you entered is " + average);

    }

}
```